# Cannot create simple table using Happybase in Python

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, thrift, happybase

I am trying to create a table using Happybase.  To start I enter the following commands get Hbase and Thrift running:

```
start-hbase.sh
hbase thrift start &
```

Once this is running I open Python's command prompt and type the following:

```
import happybase as hb
connection = hb.Connection()
connection.open()
```

However when I try to create a table:

```
connection.create_table(
'mytable',
{'cf1': dict(max_versions=10),
 'cf2': dict(max_versions=1, block_cache_enabled=False),
 'cf3': dict(),  # use defaults
}
```

I get the following error that I just don't understand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/happybase/connection.py", line 309, in create_table
    self.client.createTable(name, column_descriptors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198, in _req
    return self._recv(_api)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 210, in _recv
    fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
  File "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 429, in cybin.TCyBinaryProtocol.read_message_begin (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:6325)
  File "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 60, in cybin.read_i32 (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:1546)
  File "thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx", line 65, in thriftpy.transport.buffered.cybuffered.TCyBufferedTransport.c_read (thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c:1881)
  File "thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx", line 69, in thriftpy.transport.buffered.cybuffered.TCyBufferedTransport.read_trans (thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c:1948)
  File "thriftpy/transport/cybase.pyx", line 61, in thriftpy.transport.cybase.TCyBuffer.read_trans (thriftpy/transport/cybase.c:1472)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py", line 125, in read
    message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(message='TSocket read 0 bytes', type=4)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the server address, and possibly port:

```
connection = hb.Connection(SERVER, PORT)
```

You can probably omit the port value, as most likely the default value will match, but just in case check on what port your thrift server is listening and specify that as a numeric value